# Check if the string conforms to a certain format

Tags: python, string, unit-testing, python-2.7, string-formatting

I am trying to do some pattern matching in my unit test.

My source code has the following

```
MY_CODE = "The input %s is invalid"

def my_func():
    check_something()
    return MY_CODE % some_var
```

In my test I have something like this

```
def test_checking(self):
    m = app.my_func()
    # How do I assert that m is of the format MY_CODE???
    # assertTrue(MY_CODE in m) wont work because the error code has been formatted
```

I would like the best way of asserting the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you'd have to use a regex for that:

```
assertTrue(re.match("The input .* is invalid", m))
```

You could try to convert the format string to a regex by translating `%s` to `.*`, `%d` to `\d` and so on:

```
pattern = MY_CODE.replace('%s', '.*').replace(...)
```

*(In this simple case you can just use `startswith` and `endswith`, though.)*

Although actually I don't think you should test that at all.

Comment: Right but I do not want to have the "The input .* is invalid" in my test. I have access to the MY_CODE constant and I would like something like assertTrue(do_something(MY_CODE).match(m))

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure I agree with the "don't test this" part. It can be quite sensible to test string outputs and error messages against some format.

Comment: @larsmans Well, maybe it's the simplicity of the shown code that made me think that. Perhaps it can be sensible to test the format, but if there's a single line of code where the output is always generated and it's `return MY_CODE % some_var`, then I'd probably not test that.

Comment: Sorry I simplified it but yes in reality the code is very complex and I would like to test a) if an error message was printed and b) if yes it confirms to a format